# How to convert characters from any language to their respective unicode in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I am using `character.encode("unicode_escape"))` function that converts Devnagri  and other Indic script characters to their unicode version but this function fails when it comes to English alphbets, Numeric digits and Special characters.
Can anybody suggest any other function for this?

Comment: Some examples of what you are experiencing would be of grate use! Paste some code!

Comment: Can you give an example? `"foo".encode("unicode_escape")` works.

Comment: Since its python and we're talking unicode, you might also want to mention whether you're using 2.x or 3.x...

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3. `In[3]: ((u'य').encode("unicode_escape"))
Out[3]: 
'\\u092f'
In[4]: ((u'm').encode("unicode_escape"))
Out[4]: 
'm'
In[5]: ((u'?').encode("unicode_escape"))
Out[5]: 
'?'`

Comment: Why do you need the characters escaped? The ASCII range can be read back just fine on any Python supporting system...

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually I have a java script that only accepts UNICODE characters, that is why I need all my characters to be converted into unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The `unicode_escape` codec only converts non-ascii characters to the Unicode Escape format.  But you can format them yourself:

```
#!python3.6
# coding:utf8
import re

def escape(s):
    def replace(m):
        item = ord(m.group(0))
        if item < 0x100:
            return fr'\x{item:02x}'
        elif item < 0x10000:
            return fr'\u{item:04x}'
        return fr'\U{item:08X}'
    return re.sub(r'.',replace,s)

s = 'abcü马克'
print(escape(s))
```

Output:

```
\x61\x62\x63\xfc\u9a6c\u514b\U0001F600
```

Here's a Python 2.7 (narrow build)-equivalent...and why anyone using Unicode should switch to Python 3:

```
#!python2.7
#coding:utf8
import re

def escape(s):
    def replace(m):
        char = m.group(0)
        if len(char) > 1:
            # Python 2 uses UTF-16 surrogate pairs for Unicode above U+FFFF.
            # Manually convert a UTF-16 surrogate pair to a Unicode ordinal.
            item = (((ord(char[0]) & 0x3FF) << 10) | (ord(char[1]) & 0x3FF)) + 0x10000
        else:
            item = ord(char)
        if item < 0x100:
            return r'\x{:02x}'.format(item)
        elif item < 0x10000:
            return r'\u{:04x}'.format(item)
        return r'\U{:08X}'.format(item)
    # This regular expression detects UTF-16 surrogate pairs.
    return re.sub(ur'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|.',replace,s)

s = u'abcü马克'
print(escape(s))
```

Output (same):

```
\x61\x62\x63\xfc\u9a6c\u514b\U0001F600
```

Comment: The OP appears to be on Python 2.7, so 3.6 f-string syntax is probably not helpful. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP should have put that in his question then.  Training :)  Anyway was working on a 2.7 version after I saw the comment.  It's a good example of why to switch to Python 3 :)

Comment: No argument there. I could do with Py2 dying a terrible death so we aren't always coding with one hand tied behind our back. :-)